# Не работает навигация на многостраничном сайте

Tags: javascript, html, навигация

реализовал функцию на javascript, выглядит вот так

```
let getElement = document.querySelector('.header');

function header() {
  debugger;
  let mainHead = document.createElement('div');
  mainHead.className = 'mainHead';
  getElement.appendChild(mainHead);

  function createForm(active, text) {
    let form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('active', active);

    mainHead.appendChild(form);

    let addButton = document.createElement('button');
    addButton.className = 'buttonInMainHead'; 

    form.appendChild(addButton);

    let add_h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    add_h2.className = 'textInButton';
    let h2text = document.createTextNode(text);
    add_h2.appendChild(h2text);

    addButton.appendChild(add_h2);
  }

  createForm('/Index.html', 'Главная');
  createForm('/pages/catalog.html', 'Каталог');
  createForm('/pages/info.html', 'Информация');
}

header();
```

проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку переход не происходит. Переписывал старый html только уже на js, старый код выглядел так:

```
<div class="mainHead">
        <form action="/Index.html">
            <button class="buttonInMainHead">
                <h2 class="textInButton">Главная</h2>
            </button>
        </form>
        <form action="/pages/catalog.html">
            <button class="buttonInMainHead">
                <h2 class="textInButton">Каталог</h2>
            </button>
        </form>
        <form action="/pages/info.html">
            <button class="buttonInMainHead">
                <h2 class="textInButton">Информация</h2>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

При этом все работало, я думаю проблема в атрибуте, который я задал в js форме при создании, исправьте меня, если ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема может быть связана с тем, что вы используете неправильный атрибут "active" вместо "action" для указания URL-адреса внутри тега формы. Попробуйте заменить "active" на "action" :

```js
let getElement = document.querySelector('.header');

function header() {
  debugger;
  let mainHead = document.createElement('div');
  mainHead.className = 'mainHead';
  getElement.appendChild(mainHead);

  function createForm(active, text) {
    let form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('action', active);

    mainHead.appendChild(form);

    let addButton = document.createElement('button');
    addButton.className = 'buttonInMainHead'; 

    form.appendChild(addButton);

    let add_h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    add_h2.className = 'textInButton';
    let h2text = document.createTextNode(text);
    add_h2.appendChild(h2text);

    addButton.appendChild(add_h2);
  }

  createForm('/Index.html', 'Главная');
  createForm('/pages/catalog.html', 'Каталог');
  createForm('/pages/info.html', 'Информация');
}

header();
```